# Metodologia para planejamento de um app mobile

Tags: mobile, engenharia-de-software, metodologia, metodologia-ágil

*Background*: 
  Estava pensando em iniciar um projeto de app mobile sozinho, porém para não ser algo cansativo e sem perspectiva de termino, pensei em organizar as atividades no método **Kanban**, após priorizar os aspectos importantes do app, notei que ao ler as atividades ainda tinha dificuldade de abstrair e visualizar o produto final. 
 
  Gostaria de evitar ao máximo deixar detalhes vagos, pois sei que tudo deve ser definido antes de ser desenvolvido, evitando mudanças de rumo no meio do projeto e assim sua extensão, então pensei que poderia ser adotada uma metodologia apropriada para o estilo de desenvolvimento mobile.
  Ao procurar sobre o assunto, não consegui encontrar uma metodologia sólida, somente alguns artigos sugerindo adotar algumas posições frente ao desenvolvimento, então fiquei com algumas dúvidas como:

- Existe alguma metodologia própria pra esse tipo de desenvolvimento que não achei?
- Usar uma metodologia ágil de software comum como *scrum* é algo viável?
- Existe algo fora o **Kanban** que ajude na organização do projeto e resulte em um desenvolvimento mais rápido?
- [*Offtopic*] Usar um diagrama de classes para abstrair melhor o programa é algo necessário sendo que serei somente eu o desenvolvedor responsável?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pensar em desenvolvimento de App Mobile pode ser visto igualmente como o desenvolvimento de qualquer software.

- Você pode encontrar alguns métodos que possam ter sido criados buscando o foco exatamente no desenvolvimento mobile. Particularmente não conheço nenhum em especial. Mas acredito que sua Organização e foco é que serão primordiais na qualidade final da entrega da solução.
- O uso de metodologias ágeis tem mais a ver com a dimensão do seu projeto do que com o tipo de Software que está desenvolvendo. Desde um ERP até um Aplicativo podem ser utilizadas técnicas como *Scrum*. No final o que determina a necessidade é seu objetivo de organização das atividades de desenvolvimento. Para projetos mais extensos realmente seria uma boa forma de organizar e manter o cronograma de todas as atividades de uma EQUIPE.
- Também desconheço algo que possa atender a este requisito citado no terceiro tópico. Mas diante do seu cenário o planejamento inicial que você realizou muito provavelmente será o suficiente para que o projeto seja desenvolvido adequadamente dentro do seu tempo. A velocidade de entrega dependerá somente de você.
- Sempre que possível gosto de utilizar diagramas de classes para desenvolver meus projetos, então aconselho sim que faça também, justamente para que possa prever melhor tudo o que será criado e já filtrar possíveis falhas na implementação antes mesmo que o código tenha sido escrito.